# How to properly substitute a value to the variable used in formula in wxMaxima?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I calculated a velocity vector and its module from the equations of motion of a point in wxMaxima:

```
x:3*sin(4*t);
y:2*cos(4*t);
r:[x,y];
v:diff(r,t,1);
v_mod:sqrt(v.v);
```

Now I would like to calculate the velocity for t=5. How can I do this? When I add **(t)** and **:=** everywhere, like this:

```
x(t):=3*sin(4*t);
y(t):=2*cos(4*t);
r(t):=[x(t),y(t)];
v(t):=diff(r(t),t,1);
v_mod(t):=sqrt(v(t).v(t));
```

and then add this line at the end:

```
v_mod(5);
```

I get the following error:

```
diff: second argument must be a variable; found 5
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you say `v(5)`, you're getting `diff(<something>, 5)` and Maxima is complaining about that.

Try `v(t) := at(diff(r(u), u), u = t)` -- i.e., differentiate wrt a dummy variable `u`, and then evaluate that derivative at `u` equal to the argument `t`.

There are other ways to go about it. If `at` doesn't work for you, we can try something else.